# Executing Multiple Queries In IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice

i have an IntentService which performs a webservice call using retrofit, then on success the response (Set of queries) will be executed.
the webservice call is being made successfuly and all is well, but when executing the queries, the UI freezes then continues when the execution finishes.

shouldnt an intent service do tasks in background without affecting the UI?

code simplified:

```
@Override
public void success(Response iu, Response response) {
    //get respose (set of queires then loop over them and execute them.
    for (int i = 0; i < contentArray.length; i++) {
        String query = contentArray[i];
        MainActivity.myDataBase.execSQL(query);
}  //the amount of queries can reach 100
```

if you would like to post more code i will

Comment: Well, that depends a bit on how you implemented the `IntentService`. Since we cannot see your code, it is difficult to provide you with specific advice. Make sure that everything is done in `onHandleIntent()`.

Comment: hi thank you for your response, everything is done in onHandleIntent()... (when webservice call is successful it calls a void method that executes the queries like the one i wrote)

Comment: it is freezing on the for loop

Comment: I don't know much about retrofit, but a quick [google](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/Callback.html) shows this "Callbacks are executed on the application's main (UI) thread.".

Comment: so if i use other methods than retrofit to call on a webservice, the problem will be solved?

Comment: but the UI is freezing after i get the response and not while getting the response

Comment: Depends on these "other methods". As long as you don't do your db queries on the UI thread you should be fine.

Comment: `success()` is a method on `Callback`, and according to the docs I quoted, will run on the UI thread. Presumably the actual network code is done on another thread, but again, I don't use retrofit, so I can't tell you how or why that works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be making the Web service call using Retrofit, and in particular, using a Retrofit `Callback`. The `Callback` is designed for cases were you are initiating the query from the main application thread and you want the results to be delivered to the main application thread (e.g., to update a UI).

In your case, none of that is true.

Instead, drop the `Callback` and use Retrofit's synchronous API. So, instead of something like:

```
@GET("/group/{id}/users")
void groupList(@Path("id") int groupId, Callback<List<User>> callback);
```

use something like:

```
@GET("/group/{id}/users")
List<User> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId);
```

This way, the results will be delivered to you on the same thread that you are on, synchronously, and it will ensure that you are on the background thread for your database I/O.

BTW, if you are not doing so already, consider wrapping those database calls in a transaction -- doing ~100 individual transactions may get a little slow.